# The below code does not print output

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I want to parse xml file using perl, i want to retrieve value of Audit tag , but no output is produced.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

my $xml = <<'__EOI__';
<scanJob>
   <hosts>
      <host>
        <audit>
           <rthID>31406</rthID>
           <cve>N/A</cve>
           <cce>N/A</cce>
           <iav>N/A</iav>
           <name>OpenSSH Memory Corruption Vulnerability - (20131108) - Banner</name>
           <description>OpenSSH 6.4 </description>
           <pciReason>Default</pciReason>
           <pciPassFail>Pass</pciPassFail>
           <cvssScore>N/A</cvssScore>
           <fixInformation>Upgrade OpenSSH 6.4 or later.</fixInformation>
           <exploit>No</exploit>
           <context>TCP:22</context>
        </audit>
     </host>
  </hosts>
</scanJob>
__EOI__

my $xs = new XML::Simple;

my $data = $xs->XMLin(\$xml);
for my $scanJob (@{$data->{scanJob} }) {
                for my $hosts (@{$scanJob->hosts }) {
                for my $host (@{$hosts->host }) {
                        for my $audit (@{$host->audit }) {
                                my $rthID   = $audit->{rthID};
                                print $rthID;
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: could you post the XML you are trying to parse?

Comment: <scanJob>
 <hosts>
  <host>
   <audit>
     <rthID>31406</rthID> 
      <cve>N/A</cve> 
      <cce>N/A</cce> 
      <iav>N/A</iav> 
      <name>OpenSSH Memory Corruption Vulnerability - (20131108) - Banner</name> 
      <description>OpenSSH 6.4 </description> 
    <pciReason>Default</pciReason> 
      <pciPassFail>Pass</pciPassFail> 
      <cvssScore>N/A</cvssScore> 
      <fixInformation>Upgrade OpenSSH 6.4 or later.</fixInformation> 
      <exploit>No</exploit> 
      <context>TCP:22</context> 
     </audit>
     </host>
    </hosts>
</scanJob>

Comment: can't you edit your post? It's hard to read it from a comment

Comment: I am not able to properly edit this? Just want to say tag alignment is like below <scanjob> -> <hosts> -> <host> -> <audit> -> <rthID> means rthID is child of audit, audit is child of host ,host is child of hosts,  hosts is child of scanJob

Comment: @mirod can you please look?

Comment: @yogeshYadav Paste the XML into your question. Don't forget - 4 spaces before each line.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code, some of them due to XML::Simple:

- XML::Simple creates hashes, you can't say `$host->audit`, you need `$host->{audit}` (same with `host`)
- did you print `$data` with Data::Dumper? What's created is not what you're expecting, the top level (`scanJob`) is not created by XML::Simple, some of the levels are converted to hashes, not arrays, since you are not using the uber-important `ForceArray` option, a;so the fact that one of the element is `name` creates a hash at the lowest level

Frankly, if you want to extract the `rthID` values, I's dish XML::Simple and use XML::LibXML, XML::Twig or XML::XSH2, it would be much less of a headache:

```
use XML::Twig;
XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => { rthID => sub { print $_->text, "\n"; } })
         ->parsefile( $file1);
```

or

```
use XML::LibXML;
my $data= XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file1);
foreach my $rthid (@{$data->findnodes( '//rthID')})
  { print $rthid->textContent, "\n"; }
```

I am sure an XSH2 solution will pop up soon in this thread ;--)

Comment: Actually i dont want only rthID value which is child tag of audit, I want to retrieve 10 child tag value of audit tag. I have provided only 1  for now i.e rthID

Comment: well, I can only answer the question you asked... it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt either the XML::Twig or the XML::LibXML code to do what you want though: for XML::Twig set a handler on the `audit` tag and then use `children`, for XML::LibXML use XPath to select `audit` elements, then to get the children